# an error occured while executing doInBackground() android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am facing an issue with my code in my android app. I've not dealt with Async before and I'm unsure of how to debug the issue. For security reasons, the URL has been replaced.

```
class checkLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlStr = "http://example.com/api/?username=" + params[0] + "&password=" + params[1] + "&action=checkLogin";
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.connect();
            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String output = "";
            String str;
            while ((str= reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output += "\r\n" + str;
            }
            createMsg(output,"Debug");
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            createMsg("Encountered an error. Report this problem to the development department with steps to reproduce","Fatal Error");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
createMsg creates an android alert box.

Error:

```
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:107)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:931)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.unrealonline.timesheet.MainActivity.createMsg(MainActivity.java:55)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.unrealonline.timesheet.MainActivity$checkLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:79)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.unrealonline.timesheet.MainActivity$checkLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-07 18:19:35.066: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: As Brian Roach says, you could start by printing the Exception's stack trace within the catch statement. Also you have not actually specified what issue you are experiencing.

Comment: what does this method do  createMsg(output,"Debug");?

Comment: @Raghunandan read after the Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just a side note, you should parameterize the string passed to createMsg() in strings.xml and use createMsg(getString(R.string.encountered_an_error)); after all imagine having to change the string in every place it has been used...

Comment: i guess  createMsg(output,"Debug"); updating ui from doInbackground()

Comment: @Raghunandan the question is how I fix it though. Piovezan I am going to do that after I've got stuff working. This is my immediate priority.

Comment: you should not update ui form doinbackground move that to onPostExecute. the result of doinbackground is a parameter to onpostExecute . so based on the result you can display the error message in onpostExecute

Comment: @GtoXic you can do as suggested by ρяσѕρєя K. you can also use a handler. you should update ui only on the uithread

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use `runOnUiThread` or `Hanlder` for showing Toast or Alertbox from non UI Thread(in your case from `doInBackground`). do it as:

```
try{
 //.....your code here...
while ((str= reader.readLine()) != null) {
       output += "\r\n" + str;
     }
Your_Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createMsg(output,"Debug"); // show message here
    }
});

  return true;
}catch(Exception e){
   //use runOnUiThread for showing Alert here....
  return false;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. This worked as I wanted :)

Comment: The correct way to do it, is Using AssyncTasks... But the runOnUiThread work as well...

Answer (score 3):

The `doInBackground` method in an `AsyncTask` should not perform any activity on the display (the UI) as it is specifically not on the UI thread. Although you can achieve this using the approach posted in @ρяσѕρєя K's answer, the very point of AsyncTask was to provide an easy mechanism for accessing the UI from a background thread in a structured manner.

When you call `createMsg` from within `doInBackground`, you break this paradigm. All UI actions in an AsyncTask should, in principle, be initiated from:

- `onPreExecute`, which will be run before `doInBackground`
- `onPostExecute`, which will be run once `doInBackground` has completed
- `onProgressUpdate`, which will be run whenever `publishProgress` is called from `doInBackground`

The [Android dev page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) includes a good usage example.

In your case, it looks like you should return a success or failure code from `doInBackground` which is picked up by `onPostExecute`; it should call `createMsg` if it has received a fail code.